# Bootstrap 5 stretch div background and content center

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to use the align-items-stretch to stretch the background of a div and align-items-center to center the content (vertical!). Somehow the align-items-center won't be applied when I use a very long title.

[image]
The 'Devote' needs to be center aligned vertical with the other card

[image]
This is what should happen; vertically align the images on the same height

What am I doing wrong?

Update: Added CSS of own style + bootstrap specific from source
Update: When I apply inline min-height the content will be vertically center (which is good).

```
<div class="col-6 grow d-flex align-items-stretch">
  <div class="col-12 tile elevation-1">
  <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="col-12">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/512" alt="" class="img-fluid tile-image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 tile-product-content-horizontal" style="min-height:300px;">
    <div class="col-12 ">
        <span class="brand"> Brand name </span>
        <h3> Short title </h3>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="col-6 grow d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="col-12 tile elevation-1">
    <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="col-12">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/512" alt="" class="img-fluid tile-image">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-8 tile-product-content-horizontal" style="min-height:300px;">
      <div class="col-12 ">
          <span class="brand"> Brand name </span>
          <h3> This is a very long title which stretches the div </h3>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tile-product-content-horizontal {
          padding: 20px 40px 20px 5px;
}
.tile {
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-image: url(assets/card-chevron.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 30px center;
} 

/* BOOTSTRAP SPECIFIC */
.align-items-stretch {
    align-items:stretch !important
}

.align-items-center {
    align-items:center !important
}

.d-flex {
    display:flex !important
}
```

Comment: Add css part also

Comment: Added CSS of own style + bootstrap

Comment: How should the elements look like?

Comment: It is applied. I have just tested. Create a [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) of your code and include an image.

Comment: Ok, I've got something working: When I apply an inline style:"min-height:300px;" the element is being vertically centered (which is good). Can I do this without applying the min-height?

Comment: Sorry; Added images now as well. Example 1) The devote isn't aligning properly, Example 2) how the cards should align properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stratch the columns verticallly and then align their content vertically.

---

Do these:

1. Remove the inner .col-12 and use instead .tile-product-content-horizontal
2. Use .h-100 on the .row and remove .align-items-center
3. Use .d-flex and .alig-items-cener on the shortest columns.

```
<div class="col-6 grow d-flex align-items-stretch">
  <div class="col-12 tile elevation-1">
    <div class="row no-gutters h-100">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="col-12">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/512" alt="" class="img-fluid tile-image">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-8 d-flex align-items-center" >
        <div class="tile-product-content-horizontal">
          <span class="brand"> Brand name </span>
          <h3> This is a very long title which stretches the div </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.tile-product-content-horizontal {
  padding: 20px 40px 20px 5px;
}

.tile {
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-image: url(assets/card-chevron.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 30px center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="col-6 grow d-flex align-items-stretch">
  <div class="col-12 tile elevation-1">
    <div class="row no-gutters h-100">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="col-12">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/512" alt="" class="img-fluid tile-image">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-8 d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="tile-product-content-horizontal">
          <span class="brand"> Brand name </span>
          <h3> Short title </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-6 grow d-flex align-items-stretch">
  <div class="col-12 tile elevation-1">
    <div class="row no-gutters h-100">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="col-12">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/512" alt="" class="img-fluid tile-image">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-8 d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="tile-product-content-horizontal">
          <span class="brand"> Brand name </span>
          <h3> This is a very long title which stretches the div </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```